# MYSQL>PHP - Trouble with reworking query relating to log in authentification function, to include new set of users

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am having some trouble trying to rework a function that checks a users input log in info against info stored in a mysql table.

It basically works like this, when the user submits the log in form, their input user and pass are matched against a table in mysql.

The table would contain info such as a user id, username and password. If there is a match, the first function, "UserIsLoggedIn" returns true.

Certain pages require certain roles, or user categories, so the user is then checked for the correct role. This is a linking table that would link the user id to the role id. If the user does have the required role, the next function, "UserHasRole" returns true.

This works perfectly fine currently. But I have added a new seperate section to this site that would require certain users to be able to "log in" to the site. The problem is, that this set of users, must be kept seperate from the original group of users (which gets truncated each time there is an update from the legacy point of sale software controlling that set of user accounts) A simple idea...

But given my limited knowledge when it comes to mysql, i was hoping that some people with a bit more wisdom than me on the matter... Might like to provide some suggestions, or input in ways to go about this task.

My current query, relating to the first check, or function, looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users
WHERE id='$accNum' AND password='$password'
```

The variables would relate the the input information.

The query relating to the second check, looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users
INNER JOIN user_roles ON users.id = userId
INNER JOIN roles ON roleId = roles.id
WHERE users.id = '$accNum' AND roles.id='$role'
```

The additional variable here, relates to the required user role, this is coded into any specific page.

Now what I want to do, is have a new table, lets call it "otherUsers". Then have the function check the provided user information against the "users" table, and if no match is found, then check the info against the "otherUsers" table. Then essentially, either set of users may "log in" to the site.

Thats is how i imagine it should happen anyway, which is why I am here looking for any input or suggestions relating to this matter.

As a note though, the first group of users had an id range of 1-9999, I am assuming the second group should have a range of 10000-END, that way the linking table "user_types" can be used to link the second group of users to the different roles too.

Anyone taking to read through this should know that it has been effort appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need both sets of users to be kept separate? Or could you just add a column to the users table to flag which set a user is in (and therefore although you to delete one set completely)?

Comment: @liquorvicar Yes, they do need to be kept seperate, as i tried to explain, the `users` table is based on actual account information, imported from a point of sale system. During the import, the table gets truncated and filled with the new data, so any data not actually on the point of sale system, will be lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a UNION

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
      'OriginalUser' as UserType
    FROM 
      users
    WHERE 
      id='$accNum' AND 
      password='$password'
) UNION (
    SELECT 
      'OtherUser' as UserType
    FROM 
      otherUsers
    WHERE 
      id='$accNum' AND 
      password='$password'
)
```

Rather than using COUNT(*) you could just count the number of results. If it's zero, there's no valid user. If it's greater than one you have some kind of duplicate. Otherwise you can just check the value of 'UserType' to see which kind of user you've found.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better for your checks if you considered using [`WHERE EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html), for example for your third check it would be something like:

```
Select case when sub.t = "true" then "Found In Other users" end 
From
(
    Select distinct "true" as t 
    From otherUsers 
    Where Exists (Select * From otherUsers Where uname = @uname and PW = @pw)
) sub
where not exists
(
    select * from users where uname = @uname and pass = @pass
)
```

Comment: Going to take a bit of time for all that to soak in, but will give your link a read in the mean time, thanks for the good advice!

Comment: Forgive my cluelessness, but what is that `@uname` and `@pass` supposed to do? Why are you referring to the variables in that manner?

Comment: @BlackberryFan they are refer to the parameters you passed to the query, is this is closed to what you asked or not???

Comment: Yes your answer has been useful, but i have not been able to come up with a working version of this, so no answer for my question has been chosen as of yet. I do appreciate your input, and any else you may have! Thanks!